# Is there a single command to build and copy a cabal executable component to specified destination?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

- `cabal install --installdir=some_dir some:exe:component` builds all executables
- `cabal build --bindir some:exe:component` doesn't appear to copy anything

`cabal --version` output:

```
cabal-install version 3.10.1.0
compiled using version 3.10.1.0 of the Cabal library
```

Comment: The `cabal install` command should both build **and** install the executable.  The last line of output from the command should be `Symlinking 'executablename' to '/the/installation/directory'` (or, if you're on Windows, possibly "Copying" in place of "Symlinking").  What output do you get from your `cabal install` command?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr If I read this right, the objection to `cabal install` is that it does too much, not that it doesn't do enough. It installs executables other than the one listed on the command line, apparently.

Comment: Yes, it builds and installs all three (in my case).